# Combine forEach callback parameter with function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, jsdom

I am trying to combine a `forEach` callback parameter (`HTMLAnchorElement`/`HTMLTableCellElement` objects) with a function parameter (`string`).

What I am doing is getting the `href` of an `a` tag in one function call, and then `textContent` of a `td` tag in another function call, using the same function.

Here is my code:

```
// example usage of function
await scraper.scraper(args, 'a[href]', 'href') // get href

await scraper.scraper(args, 'table tr td', 'textContent') // get textContent

// scraper function
const scraper = async (urls, regex, property) => {
  const promises = []
  const links = []

  urls.forEach(async url => {
    promises.push(fetchUrls(url))
  })

  const promise = await Promise.all(promises)
  promise.forEach(html => {
    const arr = Array.from(new JSDOM(html).window.document.querySelectorAll(regex))
    arr.forEach(tag => {
      links.push(tag.href) // how about textContent?
    })
  })

  return links
}
```

---

Is there a way of some how combining the callback parameter `tag` from the `forEach` with the function parameter `property`?

The code below works. But what if I want to do further function calls to other properties? I don't want to add an if statement every time I make another function call, that kind of defeats the purpose of my function to be reusable.
`property === 'textContent' ? links.push(tag.textContent) : links.push(tag.href)`

Any attempt in trying to combine the two seems to go wrong. Is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property value you pass in as computed key of your el object (`tag` in your code), in order to pass the property value for the element inside the `forEach` dynamically, depending on the property you passed in

```
arr.forEach(el => {
  links.push(el[property]);
})
```